# C#, wpf and datagrid, set selectedIndex and the row is grey

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf application that use the MVVM pattern. In code, I set the selectedItem property, that binds the dataGrid property in the axml, and the row has a grey color, instead of blue.

If I select the row with the mouse, then the row is blue.

Why?

I use the binding mode "twoway" for the selectedIndex property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gray highlight is probably because it is showing the selected item, but the control itself (the `DataGrid`) doesn't have focus. The same thing occurs with `ListBox`es. Try putting a `TextBox` on your window next to the `DataGrid`. Select the row with the mouse and it'll turn blue. Then click in the `TextBox` and the selection will turn gray.